# Find the remainder when $2^{2013}$ is divided by $23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is there any general method to solving problems like finding the remainder when $2^{2013}$ is divided by $23$? And if there is i would really appreciate some pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: there is only one remainder when $2^{2013}$ is divided by 23 (or by any other positive integer, for that matter).

Comment: @symplectomorphic im sorry it was bad translation from me (the problem is from a book in another language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of modular congruences, you have: 
$$2^{2013} \equiv x (mod \ 23)$$ $x \in Z$. 
For properties of the congruences i can say: $$2^{11} \equiv 1 (mod \ 23) $$ Now i can say $2^{2013}=(2^{11})^{183}$, then
$$2^{2013} \equiv x (mod \ 23)$$
is equal to say
$$(2^{11})^{183} \equiv x (mod \ 23)$$. For the transitive property: 
$$  (1)^{183} \equiv x (mod \ 23) $$ $$ 1 \equiv x (mod \ 23) $$. Now for the symmetryc property 
$$ x \equiv 1 (mod \ 23) $$
Well, after all we can use the Euclidean algorithm for say $$x=23(n)+1$$ for $n \in Z$. The remainder not can be negative, we gonna take $n=0$, then $x=1$. So $1$ is the minimal remainder.

Comment: how do you get $2^{11} \equiv 1 (\mod23)$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $23$ is prime, so first find $2013$ mod $22$ and then apply Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Thanks! If the divisor is not a prime could you still solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, you have to replace $p-1$ for a prime with $\phi(n)$ for general $n$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: @user6395724 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at the residues of $2^n\pmod {23}$. We have $2,4,8,16,9,18,13,3,6,12,1,2,4\cdots$ which is periodic with period 11. And 2013 mod 11 = 0. So $2^{2013}=2^{0}=1\pmod{23}$